# Cells(i,j).Value not able to compare strings

Tags: loops, find, compare, cell

I have a cell in range A, containing Account 199. I am using .Cells(rownum,1) to find a string.

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Startsheet").Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "Account 199" Then 
<DO SOMEJOB> 
End If
```

In a particular sheet, in the actual postion of rownum, comparison using IF is not working and job is not done, 
but,
when a separate row is introduced above the actual position then the above comparison using IF is working properly.

Tried by replacing .Value with .Text both with Range and Cells function, but no result.

Account 188 or Account 177 seem good, but not Account 199!!

Any suggestions please.

```
 Sub test()
Dim rownum As Long
Dim startrow As Long
Dim endrow As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ant As Long
Dim wasp As Long
lastrow = Worksheets("Startsheet").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("StartSheet").Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
wasp = 1
ant = 0
startrow = 0
For rownum = 1 To lastrow
Do
''''''''''''''''''Account 199'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Startsheet").Cells(rownum, 1).Value Like "Account 199" Then
      startrow = rownum
      wasp = startrow
      ant = 0
   End If

    rownum = rownum + 1
    wasp = wasp + 1

If (ant = 2) Then Exit For
Loop Until .Cells(wasp, 1).Value = "@01\QPosted@"
If startrow <> 0 Then
ant = ant + 1
End If

endrow = rownum
rownum = rownum + 1

If ant = 2 Then
Worksheets("StartSheet").Range(startrow & ":" & wasp - 2).Copy
Sheets("Endsheet").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
Next rownum
End With
End Sub
```

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yi1dwOoprxrXaNs3WxU0LyIfQzDqRqPP?usp=sharing

[Image is here FYI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHY8p.jpg)

Comment: I think you may need to give a bit more context on where rownum's value is coming from. I'm wondering if you might be getting this issue because Cells starts at 1 but ranges at 0. The quick test might be replacing rownum by rownum+1 and seeing if the behavior improves. Also wondering if replacing = by "like" helps.

Comment: @JeremyKahan      even Like is not fetching result. any help please.

Comment: when the loop condition is true, rownum is incremented three times. It looks like as a result row 10 is never checked. It goes straight from 8 to 11. That is, if you use next rownum in for..next, doing rownum=rownum+1 twice manually as well is messing you up